# Can't start fragment from activity

Tags: java, android, overlapping

I am trying to start a fragment from activity but it doesn't work, can somebody help?

This is the **main.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    Button clickButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        clickButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    click();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void click()
    {
        clickButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.i("click","clickt");
             FragmentOne fragmentOne = new FragmentOne();
                 FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                 transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentcontainer, fragmentOne);
                 transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                 transaction.commit();
            }

        });
    }
```

This is the **main layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testfragment.MainActivity" >



     <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2" 
    android:id="@+id/fragmentcontainer">
</FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the **Fragment**

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment  {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.signup_, container,false);
}
}
```

And this is the **fragment layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: pls paste logcat here

Comment: @ConnectinglifewithAndroid there is no error in logcat :(

Comment: just paste your logcat....even if you are not seeing any error...click on button and then paste logcat

Comment: 09-05 13:48:10.689: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29080): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
09-05 13:48:10.689: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29080): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
09-05 13:48:20.049: E/SpannableStringBuilder(29080): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
09-05 13:48:20.049: E/SpannableStringBuilder(29080): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
09-05 13:48:33.769: I/click(29080): clickt

Comment: make sure in  FragmentOne you have import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; instead of import android.app.Fragment;

Comment: @KetanAhir yes it is imported-- import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; What else to do, im going crazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The problem is FrameLayout has width 0.

Change this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2" 
    android:id="@+id/fragmentcontainer">
</FrameLayout>
```

To this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentcontainer">
</FrameLayout>
```

**Explanation**: the weight attribute is a layout parameter of `LinearLayout` and not of `RelativeLayout`. The layout parameters are referred to the container of the `View`/`ViewGroup` (in this case the `View`/`ViewGroup` is your `FrameLayout`). So basically here the weight is completely ignored and the width set to 0, making the `FrameLayout` with the `Fragment` views effectively invisible

Comment: thx for the aswer Gil, but now the to layouts are overlapping. How can i only show the signup_.xml

Comment: Depends how you want it to be placed. You can use layout_below on the TextView to place it under the FrameLayout. The height of the FrameLayout can be set to wrap_content to resize depending on how big is the content. If you want to fill up as much space as use can, you can use a top-level LinearLayout and the layout_weight property set to 1 on the FrameLayout (but do not use a top-level RelativeLayout as here). Alternatively you could use a RelativeLayout with a good combination of below/above/etc. layout params. You can ask that as another question though, it is different from this one

Comment: In the comment above I meant the problem is not in signup_.xml but rather in the fact you don't align the Views in your main layout. Use the RelativeLayout.LayoutParams for that (like below/alignParentRight/etc.)

Comment: please Gil i dont know how to do it can you give me an example of how i can only show the signup_.xml

Comment: What do you mean with "only" the signup_.xml? Should this layout be not overlaid by other views with the button and the textView below it? In that case add `android:layout_below="@+id/fragmentcontainer"` to the TextView below the FrameLayout. But it is better that you post another question for that instead of commenting on here, so the community can help

Answer (score 0):

try this layout for your main.xml for time being and let me know the result

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testfragment.MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentcontainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thx for the answer, but now the two xml files are overlapping. How can i only show the signup_.xml

Comment: the issue is mainly related with your xml designing.. fragment is getting called but its not visible because of design. you can select ans and open a new question for the xml design